# how to Show Poster image on video ends using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

My HTML5 Video Control API got a shape. But now the client asks me to show Poster once video played.

Now there is a dark black background.

Please let me know how I have to do that.

```
<video width="640" height="360" x-webkit-airplay="allow" poster="asserts/poster.png" preload="" tabindex="0" class="video1">
    <source data-quality="sd" src="http://media.jilion.com/videos/demo/midnight_sun_sv1_360p.mp4"></source>
    <source data-quality="hd" src="http://media.jilion.com/videos/demo/midnight_sun_sv1_720p.mp4"></source>            
    <source data-quality="sd" src="http://media.jilion.com/videos/demo/midnight_sun_sv1_360p.webm"></source>
    <source data-quality="hd" src="http://media.jilion.com/videos/demo/midnight_sun_sv1_720p.webm"></source>            
</video>
```

And the Jquery funciton for play/ pause is:

```
/* Play/Pause */
    var gPlay = function() {
        if($hdVideo.attr('paused') == false) {
            $hdVideo[0].pause();
            $video_main_control.removeClass("hd-video-main-control-none");
            $hdVideo[0].poster.show();
        }
        else {
            $hdVideo[0].play();
            $video_main_control.addClass("hd-video-main-control-none");
        }
    };
    $video_main_control.click(gPlay);
    $hd_play_btn.click(gPlay);
    $hdVideo.click(gPlay);
    $hdVideo.bind('play', function() {
        $hd_play_btn.addClass('hd-paused-button');
            });
            $hdVideo.bind('pause', function() {
                $hd_play_btn.removeClass('hd-paused-button');
            });
    $hdVideo.bind('ended', function() {
                $hd_play_btn.removeClass('hd-paused-button');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<video width="640" height="360" x-webkit-airplay="allow" poster="asserts/poster.png" preload="" tabindex="0" class="video1" id="video_elem">       
</video>

var showBanner = function () {
    // Show your banner
};
document.getElementById("video_elem").addEventListener("ended",showBanner, false );
```

Video api has **"ended"** event for this purpose. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Media_events

Comment: I tried that..
But it simply blocks the the flow of the script.

Comment: tx Selvaraj.

what i have to write inside the function to show poster?

i don't have clue how to fetch the poster="sdfsf.png" and show in that area...